# How to limit cores on a Windows server?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

We have procured 8 core server hardware with Windows server 2012 R2, we have the application license only for 4 core server. Is there any option to limit the core on architecture level?

If not what option can be used to install the application?

Comment: Down voted, no mention of what the application is and Server 2012 R2 is licensed per cpu not core.

Answer (score 3):

Start your program with

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe "Your Program" /affinity X
```

where `X` is the processor affinity in hexadecimal value. In your case, affinity `F` would use CPU cores 0-3.

A CPU affinity table can be found from this [MSDN blog entry](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/santhoshonline/archive/2011/11/24/how-to-launch-a-process-with-cpu-affinity-set.aspx):

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a licensing, than a technical issue, in some cases particularly Microsoft, it wouldn't matter if you weren't using the other CPUs, if they were there they'd have to be licensed. Double check with your vendor to see what they allow.

Comment: +1. Sounds like asking the totally wrong question. This is much mor a legal issue first.